# cygwin to compile math library

Tags: linux, shell, cygwin

I try to compile a library with Cygwin, following instructions at http://matrixprogramming.com/2008/03/umfpack.

In section fetching and unpacking, I learn that I should use these Unix commands:

```
$ wget http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/umfpack/UMFPACK-5.2.0.tar.gz
```

I would like to rapidly try that with cygwin, but it is not working like that (with Cygwin terminal). I get the following error:

```
-bash: wget: command not found
```

could somebody tell me how to compile the thing with Cygwin, or how to adapt commands to Cygwin?

Or what other mean to compile this lib?

Comment: What exactly is not working ? What error message(s) do you get ?

Comment: @PaulR Thanks. I get: bash wget command not found

Comment: OK, so just run the cygwin installer and install wget.

Comment: @PaulR should I uninstall and reinstall? how to run it? thanks Paul.

Comment: No - just re-run the installer (go to cygwin.com and run it from there if you haven't kept it from your previous cygwin install), select wget and any other additional tools that you might want, and the installer will update any existing packages if needed and install wget and any other new tools or dependencies that you've added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `wget` installed. This is easy to fix:

- Run the original Cygwin installer ([download it again](http://cygwin.com/install.html) if you need to).
- Hit "Next >" until you get to the window titled "Select Packages"
- Type "wget" into the Search box
- Click the [+] sign next to "Web"
- Click the "Skip" on the "wget: Utility to retrieve…" line until it gives a version number.
- Keep hitting "Next >" until you're done.

You should now have wget installed and should be able to continue with your task.